# How to fix FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, jasper-reports

This is my source cord to print my invoice page. My report is  in *Java* package. I kept it inside a folder called "report".

```
    try {

        String date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(isdate.getDate());
        String time1 = istime.getValue().toString().split(" ")[3];
        date1 = date1 + " " + time1;

        String date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(redate.getDate());
        String time2 = retime.getValue().toString().split(" ")[3];
        date2 = date2 + " " + time2;

        JRTableModelDataSource dataSource = new JRTableModelDataSource(jTable1.getModel());
        String reportsource = " D:/Catering/report/report1.jrxml";
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("inid", txtInvoiceID.getText());
        params.put("cuname", txtCuName.getText());
        params.put("cuadd", txtCuid.getText());
        params.put("cutp", txtTPNo.getText());
        params.put("isdate", date1);
        params.put("redate", date2);
        params.put("advance", txtAdvance.getText());
        params.put("due", txtDue.getText());
        params.put("total", txtGtotal.getText());
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportsource);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");
    } catch (Exception e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "jasper error"+e);
    }
```

Comment: Where, **exactly**, is the report located (in relation to you your program)?  You should also pre-compile you `jrxml` files to `jasper` and load those at runtime, it will save +10 seconds of compilation time...

Comment: report is in netbeans packege's folder name called report. Can explane me how to pre compile. I'm using netbeans 7.3

Comment: Is the report inside the projects `src` directory?

Comment: no my project name is Catering. report is inside that Catering directory with src, build, dist etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better make the report an embedded resource, but where possible you should not rely on absolute paths, as these may change between installs...

Try changing

```
String reportsource = " D:/Catering/report/report1.jrxml";
                       ^---- Did you notice the white space here?
```

To

```
String reportsource = "report/report1.jrxml";
```

It is, also, generally better to pre-compile the report so you don't need to do it at run time...

You could write a simple program that compiled it for you using something like...

```
String templateFile = "report/report1.jrxml"
String compiledReport = "report/report1.jasper"
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(templateFile, compiledReport);
```

The method takes two `String`s, basically one is the `jrxml` file and other is the expected `jasper` file.

You could use [JasperReports' Ant task](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/antcompile/) and make apart of your build process.

Or you could use iReports...

Once compiled, you can simply load the `jasper` file at run time...

```
String compiledReport = "report/report1.jasper";
JasperReport report = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(compiledReport );
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);
```

**Updated with Quick Compile example**

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;

public class QuickCompile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String template = "...";
            String compiled = "...";
            JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(template, compiled);

            // Just as a test...
            JasperReport jr = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(compiled);            

        } catch (JRException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }            
    }

}
```

Comment: The compilation process should be a separate step unrelated to the execution of your program.  Just like you need to compile the `*.java` files before you can give them to a client, you should compile the `*.jrxml` files as well.  This means, at run time, they've already being compiled and will load and fill quickly, rather than wasting time compiling the report each and every time you want to use it. The only reason to ever compile a report at runtime is because you have built the report dynamically

Comment: I thought I did.  It's a separate process.  Remove the complication portion to either a separate class or better, project and compile the report manually whenever it changes.  You could also use the Ant task provided by Jasper and make it a part of you build process.  You should never have to compile this type of report at runtime.

Comment: You mean `JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile`?  Did you update the `import`s?

Comment: In the class with the `JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile` hit `ctrl+shift+I`, Netbeans will repair the imports automatically (or as best as it can).  `JRLoader` comes from `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader` if that doesn't work

Comment: I've added a quick compile example, which based on code that I use.  Are you sure you have the required JasperReport's jars linked to the project?

Comment: It is working. I'm sorry I didn't saw your updated answer. It is working. Great !.

Comment: What version of JasperReports are you using?  Have your tried just `loadOject` instead?

Comment: Hang on, I'm using 4.8, I have 5.1 laying around, I'll take a look

Comment: 5.1 seems to still have `JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(String)`, but you could try `JRLoader.loadObject(File)`.  I have `jasperreports-5.1.0.jar`, `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar`, `commons-collections-2.1.1.jar`, `commons-digester-1.7.jar`, `commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar` in my class path as well...

Comment: wait till I'm adding them

Comment: I used loadObject(File). That method is recognizing. And should I put these cords also in a new file. And call that classes to main source filr? String compiledReport = "report/report1.jasper";
JasperReport report = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(compiledReport );
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);

Comment: You should compile the report as a separate process.  You should only do this if the report changes (ie you make updates or modifications to the original .jrxml file).  Otherwise, at runtime, you should only ever load the .jasper file.  It can many seconds to compile a report, but only a few to actually fill and export.

Comment: I made that quickCompile.java file and brought it like that.                                       params.put("total", txtGtotal.getText()); // this is a paramerter.
new Controler.QuickCompile();
String compiledReport = "report/report1.jasper";
JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(compiledReport);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, dataSource);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");             I changed jasperreport to report. You can see it two lines beofre. Now I'm having null pointer exception. Why is that.

Comment: `NullPointerException` where?

Comment: I put some joptionpane to find error. I think nullpointer exception is from these lines.             JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(compiledReport);
           //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "sucess3");
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, dataSource);
          //   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "sucess4");

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38599/discussion-between-madprogrammer-and-dilini)

Comment: By the ways its great to have your effort on this.